# Horizontal ScrollView Loop in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel, horizontalscrollview, react-native-scrollview

Checked different settings and sources, but can’t find the way to make an infinite horizontal scrolling with React Native, so that e.g. when the last image is reached, the next gesture would lead to the first image. Am I missing a setting, or is there a more sophisticated way of doing this? Please advise and if possible, share some code. Using external libraries is very undesirable.

[image]

Comment: `react-native-snap-carousel` library clones the first n elements and adds to the end of the list when close to end, and it goes on and on. You can try to implement something like that. But there are no clean ways to do it. https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/doc/PROPS_METHODS_AND_GETTERS.md#loop https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/src/carousel/Carousel.js#L388

Comment: You should share at least partial code to help you